# Parking Light Switch Engages Head Lights

Tags: ford, headlight, lights, explorer

On my 1996 Ford Explorer when I turn the knob for my headlights (3 positions, 1 for off, 2 for parking lights, 3 for headlights) to position 2 it turns on my headlights, when I turn to position 3 it also activates the headlights.

Why does position 2 engage the head lights instead of the parking lights?

Comment: I'd suggest the switch is probably worn out, but that would be a SWAG on my part.

Comment: SWAG? -- How would I check the switch?

Comment: Does the car have Auto Lamps? Is there a sensor on the rear view mirror? It could be a switch or the car is designed to do this.

Comment: SWAG = Silly Wild Arse Guess ... I really don't have an answer as to how to check it other than replacement. I'm sure you could pull it out and run a continuity test on it, but you'd have to find a schematic to figure out what is supposed to do what.

Comment: @Ben - no the vehicle does not have auto-lamps, and no switch on the rear-view mirror.  Up until recently position 2 would engage parking lights and position 3 would engage head lights.  I only noticed it today as I replaced a burnt out headlight.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - by switch do you mean the knob that I am actually turning to the left of the steering wheel that engages the lights?

Comment: Yes, the entire thing all the way to the column equates to the switch.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 - any diagram or images I can use to trace from the switch to the column?

Comment: Those Ford rotary switches tend to break and do just that. Thankfully its really cheap to replace and you can do it yourself. This is the switch: http://www.justanswer.com/uploads/FordKnowledge/2008-11-13_150710_headlight_switch_96_explorer.gif    Here is how to do  it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ROLzKlwSb68    The part:http://www.ebay.com/itm/OEM-Ford-Explorer-Mountaineer-Headlight-Switch-3L5Z11654BA-Green-Bulb-/161938358151?fits=Year%3A1996|Make%3AFord|Model%3AExplorer&hash=item25b4473f87:g:clQAAOSwzrxUwjMf&vxp=mtr

Comment: @racefever - thanks for that info!  I'll order that part and see if it resolves.

Comment: To test the switch, it get's power from the tan/white wire, in park lamp it sends power to the white/light blue wire, and in head lamp position it sends power to white/light blue & red/yellow wires.

Comment: @Ben - forgive my lack of knowledge here, but how would that allow me to test?

Comment: In a correctly working switch, in the off position you wouldn't have power on wht/lt blu or red/yel. In the park lamp position it would only have power on the wht/lt blue wire. In the Head lamp position it sends power to the red/yel and wht/lt blu wire. If none of these are true than the switch is bad.

Comment: Yeah, test it before replacing it like @Ben.

Comment: You could also disconnect the switch connector and jump power from tan/wht to wht/lt blu and if the headlights come on than the problem isn't in the switch but in the wiring.

Comment: Somebody write this guy an answer!!! :o)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the contacts in the light switch are shorted.

In a correctly working switch,

- In the off position you wouldn't have power on white/light blue or
  red/yellow.
- In the park lamp position it would only have power on the white/light
  blue wire.
- In the Head lamp position it sends power to the red/and white/light
  blue wire.

If none of these are true than the switch is bad.

You could also disconnect the switch connector and jump power from tan/white to white/light blue and if the headlights come on than the problem isn't in the switch but in the wiring.